# Website loads very slow only at first (initial) visit in Chrome browser

Tags: apache, google-chrome, debian, webserver

I have web server Debian + Apache

When I open my site (just html file without PHP etc scripts) in Chrome  browser it's load very slow (always = 21 sec) only at first time! When I refresh (after few seconds) page it's load very fast, but if I wait a minute and refresh the page again, I have to wait another 21 seconds for it to load again. The page load delay on the first visit occurs only in the Chrome browser, everything works normally in Firefox even on the first visit. If I don't use a domain address, (I'm, accessing the website directly via the IP address), then the website loads correctly in Chrome even on the first visit.

The problem occurs on different clients computers, but only with the Chrome browser

PS I have a 408 errors in apache logs.

[image]

Comment: What are the first errors in Apache logs? It seems to me a misconfiguration of Apache (so you should go to ServerFault sister site). And you say without PHP, but you are reading a PHP file (PHP is probably called, because of extension, with possibly protections, etc., also if you do not have PHP code). HTTPS could gives you problems (timeout to find certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Company server DNS returns 2 different IP addresses for this domain address. Should return one IP, because second IP address doesent exists. Firefox works correctly for this incorrect DNS server configuration